# PHP Can't use if condition by captcha and user login

Tags: php

I have 2 form in same page.
First form if user login it not use captcha.
Second form if user not login then use captcha.

This code work when use captcha.

```
if(md5($_POST['captcha']) == $_SESSION['captchaKey']){

$name = (isset($_POST['txtUserFirstName']))?
$_POST['txtUserFirstName']:'';
$phone = (isset($_POST['txtUserPhone']))?
$_POST['txtUserPhone']:'';
$email = (isset($_POST['txtUserEmail']))?
$_POST['txtUserEmail']:'';
```

I edit code by use OR for check if user login then not use captcha like this.

```
if((md5($_POST['captcha']) == $_SESSION['captchaKey']) || (isset($_SESSION['plaincart_customer_id']))){
```

But it show error like this.

Notice: Undefined index: captcha in

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\paidForm.php on line 18
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: share form also ?

Comment: Show the form, but you might have to change your first if condition to: `(isset($_POST['captcha']) && md5($_POST['captcha']) == $_SESSION['captchaKey'])`